# Custom background image for each page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, background-image

I'm using Jquery Mobile to develope a mobile app. I'm using one custom theme but would like to use different page background images for the different sections. I'm currently using this code:

```
.ui-overlay-a,
.ui-page-theme-a,
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
background: transparent !important;

background: url('images/bgimage.jpg') !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-attachment:fixed !important;
background-size:100% 100% !important;

text-shadow: 0 0 0;
```

which works fine, but the same background image appears on all pages.

How do I *customise* each page to show a different background image but still use the same theme i.e. in my case a?

Comment: apply a `style` block on the head of each page and set a specific background

Comment: you can add on each page with different background .ui-page{
        background:url(images/bgimage.jpg) no-repeat left top;
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each page a class e.g. `custom1`, `custom2`, etc.

```
<div data-role="page" class="custom1">
</div>

<div data-role="page" class="custom2">
</div>
```

And for each class, assign a different background

```css
.ui-page-theme-a.custom1,
.ui-page-theme-a.custom1 .ui-panel-wrapper {
  background: url(custom1.png);
}

.ui-page-theme-a.custom2,
.ui-page-theme-a.custom2 .ui-panel-wrapper {
  background: url(custom2.png);
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgw08u4s/)**

Comment: This option can create more problems than you might fix. Be aware that this solution with large background images will work, but can increase loading time.

Comment: @Leon note that jQuery Mobile pages (divs) are in DOM once framework is initialized. However, only one page (div) is visible the rest are hidden. This is case of _Multi-Page Model_. in _Single Page Model_, external pages are loaded via Ajax and only 2 pages are in DOM. So it's either a CSS solution or a JS one.

Comment: just saw the jQuery Mobile part of it - you're right, my bad.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. For now this option works fine. Sorry for my delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sorry I misread, I thought you were entering the img-urls through jquery. That might be the way to go. That way you keep your css clean. Insert it with jQuery.

page 1

```
 background: url('images/bgimage-p1.jpg') !important;
```

page 2

```
background: url('images/bgimage-p2.jpg') !important;
```